# Как правильно использовать vuex?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, api, vuex

У меня есть стандартное api приложение на vue+laravel. Решил начать пользоваться vuex. Допустим, у нас есть посты в бд. На каком моменте я должен занести все посты в хранилище? Допустим, пользователь перешёл по ссылке 'posts/1', а по ссылке '/posts' не переходил и не собирается. Нужно ли мне всего для одного поста загружать весь state, а после уже копаться в нем? Или это нужно делать по другому?

Comment: Ну так добавьте этот пост в `vuex`. А что вы подразумеваете под фразой  - `загружать весь state`?

Comment: "Загружать весь state.posts" вначале работы приложения и забирать нужный пост с этого массива. Либо добавить отдельно state.post и забирать с api нужный пост. То есть интересует что из этого выбрать, либо может есть какой то вариант получше?

Comment: @Kuraveshka вы не должны загружать сразу весь `state.posts` в начале работы приложения, вы должны запрашивать контент по мере его необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Vuex делает работу намного проще и веселее. Если вы новичок, могут возникать ситуации, когда вам сложно решить, нужно ли использовать Vuex в определенных областях вашего приложения. Следуйте своему инстинкту. Вы достигнете высокой скорости довольно быстро.

По мере надобности вы можете загрузить лист всех постов или по отдельности.
Но скорее всего вы загрузите весь массив постов и оттуда выберется нужный вам.